# Docker: /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 6: [: : integer expression expected

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Docker displays the following error when I run a docker-compose but I don't see what fails on the yml.

```
PS C:\atlassian-docker> docker-compose up
Starting atlassian-docker_jira_1         ... done
Recreating atlassian-docker_confluence_1 ... done
Attaching to atlassian-docker_jira_1, atlassian-docker_confluence_1
jira_1        | stat: can't stat '/opt/atlassian/jira/conf/server.xml': No such file or directory
jira_1        | /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 6: [: : integer expression expected
jira_1        | /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 21: /opt/atlassian/jira/bin/start-jira.sh: No such file or directory
confluence_1  | stat: can't stat '/opt/atlassian/confluence/conf/server.xml': No such file or directory
confluence_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 6: [: : integer expression expected
confluence_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 29: /opt/atlassian/confluence/bin/start-confluence.sh: No such file or directory
atlassian-docker_jira_1 exited with code 127
atlassian-docker_confluence_1 exited with code 127
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
    version: '3'
services:
  jira:
    image: 'cptactionhank/atlassian-jira-software:7.11.2'
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    volumes:
      - 'C:\atlassian-docker\var\atlassian\jira:/var/atlassian/jira'
      - 'C:\atlassian-docker\opt\atlassian\jira:/opt/atlassian/jira'

  confluence:
    image: 'cptactionhank/atlassian-confluence:6.10.2'
    ports:
      - '8090:8090'
      - '8091:8091'
    volumes:
      - 'C:\atlassian-docker\var\atlassian\confluence:/var/atlassian/confluence'
      - 'C:\atlassian-docker\opt\atlassian\confluence:/opt/atlassian/confluence'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the Docs the installation files live in `/opt/atlassian/jira` and `/opt/atlassian/confluence` I think you should not override them by mounting to your local folders in `compose`

I think this folder is now empty: `/opt/atlassian/jira/conf/server.xml: No such file or directory`

Comment: You are right, I was misunderstanding how docker actually works. When you map a local volumen it get the files from that path. I thought you was fetching files from the container.